# Working with small 2D parts of big 2D array and moving around it

Tags: c++, arrays

I have one big 2D array and I want change values in smaller 2D. I can't just get some results.
I have something like that (for 16x16 array f.e.)

```
int Down8 = 0;
int Right8 = 0;

        for (int Down = 0; Down < 16; Down+8)
        {
            for (int Right = 0; Right < 16; Right+8)
            {
                Right8 = Right;
                Down8 = Down;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    {
                        matrixZ[j][i] = TEST[Right8][Down8];
                        Right++;
                    }
                    Down++;
                    Right8 = Right;
                }
                dctTransform(matrixZ);
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    {
                        matrixZ[j][i] = matrixZ[j][i] / Quant50[j][i];
                    }
                }
                zigZagMatrix(matrixZ, 8, 8);
            }
        }
```

For 2D 16x16 my function zigZagMatrix should return 4 lines into file (because 16x16 array has 4 8x8 arrays) but only returns 2. 640x480 array should return 4800 lines ( 640/8*480/8 ), returns 60.
Where am I blind/wrong?
All functions I have works with 8x8 array so all of it is loops problem.

Comment: What language is this? Please edit your question to include the language

Comment: `Down+8` and `Right+8` need to be `Down+=8` and `Right+=8`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Ok It's working now. This "Down+8 and Right+8 need to be Down+=8 and Right+=8." helped and I've changed Right++ and Down++ to Right8++ and Down8++